# Laravel Telescope error "The Mix manifest does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

I'm having trouble running telescope in an environment with apache + php 8.1 on a centos 8 server.

i would not like to install node on this machine to fix the problem, i kept the same folder name for publishing "/var/www/public"

I tried using `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-assets --force` but was unsuccessful.

the same project on my local machine runs normally

[image: telescope]

Comment: If you see it, you will have the answer. "Did you forget to run `npm ci && nom run dev`?"

Comment: if you use `mix` anywhere you will need the mix manifest. If you don't want to install node on the target machine then you could use the local node installation to compile assets and then upload them along with the generated manifest to the server. It's not the best idea though because you might end up dragging environment variables from your local in your remote server

Comment: it was permission problem in the telescope folder